# Android Java: Show the value only of `id` when a listrow is selected

Tags: java, android

So this is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.merken);

    DatabaseStuff dbStuff = new DatabaseStuff(this);

    itDetails = new Intent(Merken.this, MerkDetails.class);
    lstMerken = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewMerken);

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
        this,
        dbStuff.getMerken(),
        R.layout.merkcell,
        new String[] { "name", "id" },
        new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.id }
    );
    lstMerken.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
    lstMerken.setAdapter(adapter);
    lstMerken.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> aV, View vW, int pos, long lng) {
            Log.v("YH", lstMerken.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());

            //MerkDetails.MerkUid = lstMerken.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            //startActivity(itDetails);
        }                 
    });
}
```

The ouput that I get now is: `{name="someName", id="187"}`

My question is how do I get to ouput only `187`, so only the value of `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  String uid = (String)((TextView) vW.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
```

Comment: You might want a `.toString()` at the end.

Comment: @YassineHoussni "Didn't work, sorry" in the sense, what is the problem.?

Comment: I take it back, it worked !!!, sorry for the too fast conclusions, I had to edit the code first though, this is the code: `String uid = (String)((TextView) vW.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText();`